# How to ask an employer by email if having a bank account is necessary?

Tags: politeness, email

> Kindly let me know if having a UK bank account is necessary, as unfortunately I have not applied for bank account yet.

What do you reword it to be more elegant and polite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is great, you just need the indefinite article on the second mention of the bank account:

> *Kindly let me know if having a UK bank account is necessary, as unfortunately I have not applied for* **[a]** *bank account yet.*